# why dyntopo subdivides mesh where it doesn't needed?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt, remesh

here in this GIF image you can see i modeled and union-ed some ornamental together using boolean then i wanted to smooth the seams together but with a higher resolution but the problem is when ever i try to do this with dyntopo it fills everywhere with high resolution what should i do ?

[image]

Comment: No help here ??

Comment: DynTopo has 4 different options for the detailing. Which one do you use? (dropdown menu). The default one is *Relative Detail*" and depends on the distance between the viewport's point of view and the model. That is, the closer you get the more detail it adds. But there are also *Constant* and two other options...

Comment: @Blunder hi thanks , everyone , all of them jesus ... !